# xpath selecting text after a certain element or between elements

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to use xpath to select all the text within the  elements:

1. between the h3 elements "Hay Point" and "Darymple Bay"
2. after h3 element "Darymlple Bay"

I've got this xpath syntax working which selects all the text within the td tags after  `<h3>Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal</h3>`.

```
.//h3[2]/following::td/text()
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to select all the text between the  tags that fall between `<h3>Hay Point Coal Terminal</h3>` and `<h3>Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal</h3>`

A sample of the structure of the html is below:

```html
<h3>Hay Point Coal Terminal</h3>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td headers="table06762r1c1" tabindex="0">July       
</td><td style="text-align: left;" 
headers="table06762r1c2">4,517,445</td>
<td headers="table06762r1c3">4,261,253</td>
<td headers="table06762r1c4">4,057,239</td>
<td headers="table06762r1c5">3,535,507</td>
</tr>

<h3>Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal</h3>
<tr><td headers="table06762r1c1">July</td><td style="text-align: left;" 
headers="table06762r1c2">5,462,591</td>
<td headers="table06762r1c3">5,625,700</td>
<td headers="table06762r1c4">5,816,977</td>
<td headers="table06762r1c5">5,396,644</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please don't post images in the question; edit the question, add a representative sample of the html and your exact desired output.

Comment: i've edited the post

Comment: Much better; now, given your sample html, what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: the text between the <td> tags such as 5,625,700. 
I managed to select the text after the "Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal" with this xpath `.//h3[2]/following::td/text()`

But I'm having trouble figuring out the xpath syntax to use to select the text between "Hay Point Coal Terminal" and "Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and given the html in the question, in order to get text nodes related to the `<h3>Hay Point Coal Terminal</h3>` node, try:

```
//h3[1]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/text()
```

Output:

```
July     
4,517,445
4,261,253
4,057,239
3,535,50
```

To get those related to the `<h3>Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal</h3>` node, use:

```
//h3[2]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/text()
```

or just

```
//h3[2]/following-sibling::tr/td/text()
```

Output:

```
July
5,462,591
5,625,700
5,816,977
5,396,644
```

To get both:

```
//h3/following-sibling::tr/td/text()
```

Comment: thanks but I've simplified the html. Also the <td> tags aren't sibling of the <h3> element. There are many rows of data ie multiple <td> tags. The xpath I've used can grab all the text between the <td> tags after `<h3>Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal</h3>`

But now I want to grab all the text between the <td> tags that are between `<h3>Hay Point Coal Terminal</h3>` and `<h3>Dalrymple Bay Coal Terminal</h3>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to group those you would do something like:

```
for h3 in response.css('h3'):
  item = {
    "h3": h3.css('*::text').extract()[0],
    "tds": h3.css('* + tr td::text').extract()
  }
```